# Android app can't connect to server over phone network

Tags: android, mysql, file-upload, xampp, database-connection

I have built an android app that connects to a remote server and uploads or downloads a picture file. The app works fine over wifi. But when I run the app on the phone network it crashes. Any idea why this happens? Thanks in advance. I am using xampp.

Comment: Can you post the crash report?